# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CaDataGroup_Insert, Line 88 Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error

Here is the line that it is referencing:

```
@VALUE=IIF(VALUE_FLAG='Y',DEFAULT_QUANTITY*RATE,NULL),
```

which results in this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CaDataGroup_Insert, Line 88
>   Incorrect syntax near '='

I am at a loss here

Comment: `SELECT @@version` Probably you are using version lower than SQL Server 2012 or your compatibility mode is too low.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) is supported from SQL Server 2012 and above. You could use `CASE` instead:

```
@VALUE=CASE WHEN VALUE_FLAG='Y' THEN DEFAULT_QUANTITY*RATE END
```

Default for `ELSE` is `NULL` so we could omit it.

Comment: I think you may write "supported in SQL Server 2012+"